# ActionScript 3.0 Converting XML format to String

Tags: xml, actionscript

Sorry guys newbie here.

this is my code:

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader =  new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("faculty_data.xml"));

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);
                                               function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
{   
var xml:XML = XML(event.target.data);

var result1:String = xml.faculty.(@Wordlookup.match(/Sanchez/)).college.toString();
trace(result1); 
trace output ---> <college>COB</college>
             ---> <college>COE</college>
```

but I want an output like this:
COB
COE

Hope someone can help me... I did try to Google it...

sorry here's my XML

```
     <facultylist> 
    <faculty Wordlookup="Maria Rosario"> 
        <id>1</id> 
        <fullName>Maria Rosario</fullName> 
        <college>CED </college>
        <department>ELMD</department>
    </faculty> 
   <faculty Wordlookup="Liza Sanchez"> 
        <id>2</id>   
        <fullName>Lysa Sanchez</fullName>  
        <college>CED </college>
        <department>Marketing</department>
    </faculty> 
   <faculty Wordlookup="Melany Sanchez"> 
        <id>3</id>     
        <fullName>Melany Sanchez</fullName>
        <college>CLA </college>
        <department>Marketing</department>
    </faculty> 
</facultylist>
```

Comment: Can you please post a snippet of the XML you want to parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know how your XML look like, but I presume you also filter for @Wordlookup == "Sanchez".

Could you please try this:

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader =  new URLLoader();
xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest("faculty_data.xml"));

xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, xmlLoaded);

function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void
{   
    var xml:XML = XML(event.target.data);

    var lstXML:XMLList = xml.faculty.(@Wordlookup.match(/Sanchez/)).college;

    for each(var child:XML in lstXML)
    {
        trace(String(child));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! it worked! just add "var" ----> for each(var child:XML in lstXML)

Comment: yes, missed the var :)  sorry I wrote that from my head. Glad it works

Comment: hi sir adrian... is there a way that I can change /Sanchez/ into a variable? i tried changing it into a variable but my search turns into a case-sensitive one... like --->  var nameXML:XMLList = xml.faculty.(@Wordlookup.match(gvar)).college;

Comment: i was able to answer my own question =) 

gvar =  searchField.text;
var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp(gvar, "i"); 
var nameXML:XMLList = xml.faculty.(@Wordlookup.match(pattern)).fullName;